# Selecting child items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have HTML code:

```
<ul id="top_nav">
<li >
    <a href="#">
        <span>About</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <a href="#"><span>News</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">
                <span>News1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>News2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Contacts</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I need to select **News1** item.  I try:

```
#top_nav li ul li .active a span{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

But still no good. You can try by yourself at http://jsfiddle.net/dCGQ2/2/

So any ideas about that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#top_nav li ul li.active a span`

Notice no space before `.active`. That means that the element (`li` in this case) has the class `active`. With a space, it means a child element with class `active`.

Comment: `<pedantic>` You can do it without mentioning ul `</pedantic>`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match "A list item that is a member of the active class" (`li.active`) but you are saying "A member of the active class that is a descendent of a list item" (`li .active`).

Get rid of the space.